# BOM from high resolution photo of PCB

Tags: pcb, bom

Would it be possible for an engineer (which I'm not) to produce a relatively accurate BOM from high resolution photos of a PCB?

Comment: I'd say it's possible if the PCB uses relatively common parts from well known manufacturers..

Comment: Not if the PCB has no parts on it... You might be able to guess some major components, but the markings on a PCB, especially if it's dense, probably won't tell you much about what's supposed to be populated on it. If a PCB is being assembled manually by an engineer, the technician is probably going to have the schematic beside them, and there's often no room to put all the details on the board.

Comment: yeah, it has all the components on it.

Comment: If the board is stuffed, then a lot of the components can be identified, but it will depend. For example, small chip  passives (0402/0201) are often unmarked so there's no way to know how much resistance/capacitance they have. ICs will usually have some kind of marking on them. Whether or not you can identify the part number from that alone varies. So: you can probably get an idea of how the board works by looking at it (watch teardown videos for an example of this), but an exact BOM will probably be much harder.

Comment: @exvance It will depends heavily on the technology used on the PCB. It will bea easier to get BOM on a through-hole board than on an SMD board, since large amount of SMD components aren't even marked!

Comment: Is your purpose to reverse engineer the PCB, or just do a teardown-style estimate of e.g. cost, power etc? The latter is feasible; the former ... not so much with surface mount.

Comment: @tummychow small passives? pfft, large passives too. caps up to 1206 have no markings, and soon neither will smd resistors of any size since the two major producers have ditched them.

Comment: @Passerby I remember hearing something about the resistor markings being ditched. My comment was derived from a copy of IPC SM-782 (which is probably now out of date; I found it floating around online) which claims resistors of 0805 and above should be marked. I didn't remember it at the time, but the document also notes that ceramic chip caps are typically unmarked.

Answer (score 9):

There is no right answer to this question in the way that it is phrased, other than 'Maybe'.

It all depends on the construction of the PCB assembly (PCA).

Many modern components, especially the very small ones, don't have proper markings or sometimes any markings at all.

Instead of marking their identity, they have a manufacturer code.
E.g. (And this is not a true example) instead of SN74AVC1G14, it might have just 'Y14' printed on it as there is not room to print more.

Also crafty manufacturers either use devices that they have been sourced with markings removed, or remove them themselves, e.g. by scratching them out.

Or, in the case of many passive components, they normally have no markings. In this case it is often possible (depending on their circuit connections) to measure the component in circuit using a multimeter, though often this is not accurate enough and you need to remove it and make a measurement out of circuit, perhaps using an LCR bridge.

Some PCBs have passive components, (inductors, capacitors and resistors) embedded inside.  Although these would not appear on a BOM (bill of materials), they are still part of the circuit. This make reverse engineering the circuit (and not the BOM which is what you want) very difficult.

Lastly, some components are programmable, so even if you know what they are, you can't easily read their contents, once programmed they become a different part.  Sometime these can be read using specialist kit, sometimes reading them is impossible.

So it ***is*** possible to reverse engineer a BOM ***from a PCA image*** if:

- The PCA has no components with their markings removed, **and**
- No components without markings which no person has separately measured, **and**
- No programmable parts which you can't read their contents.

Answer (score 3):

> **[Is it] possible ... to produce a ... BOM from ... photos of a PCB?**

**Rarely**

At a minimum, with any recent nontrivial PCB, it would be necessary to remove some of the components and measure their value. *You can't do this if all you have is a set of photographs*.

Comment: In many cases though - particularly with a digital design - you can figure out workable values based on what is necessary for a given purpose.  So while it's correct you can't do it from the picture itself, you may be able to do it from the picture and information (chip data sheets, etc) that the picture points you to.

Comment: No is pretty definitive, and incorrect. Depends on the complexity of the board and how closely it follows a reference design. Rarely would be a better answer.

Comment: I agree with your "at a minimum" qualifier since even measuring component values might not be enough to produce an accurate BOM. One (analogue) design of mine in production uses SMD ceramic capacitors which must be C0G dielectic and be rated at 500V. I have to watch the sub-contract manufacturers carefully to make sure they don't substitute cheaper components on the basis of the value alone - which has been known!

Comment: Agree, with your important qualifier "nontrivial", and the difference between trivial and nontrivial may not be obvious to a lay person. Some may be digital and/or be essentially the same as a reference design. If its nontrivial the reverse engineering person really needs to understand the circuit perhaps even better than the original designer (since it may only work by some serendipitous choice of bits). In particular, custom magnetics or any non-bypass ceramic capacitors are an issue, and anything RF or analog that isn't dead simple and obvious is going to require disassembly and testing.